# redirect stderr to stdout to console and two files

Tags: powershell, stdout, stderr

I have a PowerShell script that calls a function. I am trying to accomplish all of these but am not sure how:

1. write STDOUT to console **and** `out.txt`
2. write STDERR to console **and** `out.txt` **and** `err.txt`
3. make sure all STDOUT and STDERR output is stil in the order it generated

This is what I have so far which writes STDOUT and STDERR to a file but it doesn't do the rest of what I need.

```
function doIt() {
    "hi"
    $test["a"]["b"]
    "bye"
}

doIt 2>&1 | Tee-Object out.txt
```

Comment: What is the value of $test?

Comment: `$test` doesn't exist. I put it there to force an error.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work:

```
function doIt() {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()
    "hi"
    $test["a"]["b"]
    "bye"
}

doIt -ErrorVariable e 2>&1 | Tee-Object out.txt
$e > err.txt
```

This will write the error file in a second step, though. I don't think you can merge *and* not-merge the error output stream at the same time.